# What can i use instead of redux for next.js

Tags: redux, next.js, global-state

Next-wrapper-redux is not good solution for global state management. I have tried use it 4 times in next.js and every time it doesn't work. What can i use instead for global state in next.js? I just need in sever-side-props function, dispatch data to global state. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you need a global state? You could maybe just use react-query and a context for smaller data. Then you could avoid a redux store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a next developer and I use context api for state managment.and l suggest you to use it. Thanks!